# glowing effect of view disables button in it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have `uiscrollview` with some buttons in it. I want to make one particular button to glow.

I made glowing-pulsating effect of button with following code:

(button in UIView)

```
- (IBAction)selectChampionAction:(id)sender{
    if ( self.timer ) {
            // Stop timer
            [self.timer invalidate];
            self.timer = nil;
            // Workaround: we have to return the layer's delegate property to what it was
            // Otherwise, we will encounter an unexpected result
            self.viewForGlowing.layer.delegate = self.viewForGlowing;
        } else {
            // Woraround: UIView's layer property does not support animation by default
            // assigning nil to layer's delegate property enables the animation somehow.
            self.viewForGlowing.layer.delegate = nil;
            // Start timer
            self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerExpired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
            [self.timer fire];
        }
}


 - (void) timerExpired:(NSTimer *) timer
{
    if ( self.viewForGlowing.layer.shadowRadius == 20 ) {
        // Increase

        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];

        self.viewForGlowing.layer.shadowRadius = 30; 
        self.viewForGlowing.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
        [CATransaction commit];

    } else {
        // Decrease

        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
        self.viewForGlowing.layer.shadowRadius = 20;
        self.viewForGlowing.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
        [CATransaction commit];
    }
}
```

But when i press other buttons glowing button stops response.

I suppose that this happens because of this line of code

> self.viewForGlowing.layer.delegate = nil;

---

My Questions:

- Are there other approaches to make UIButton glow?
- How to make button response after other buttons pressed?

Comment: For question one: You can add filters in the View Effects Inspector. There just use a filter that fits well. 
And question two: "assigning nil to layer's delegate property enables the animation somehow.". I think this is what you should do research for.